# Авторизация приложения telethon

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telethon

Всем привет, проблема такого рода, есть телеграм-бот, который осуществляет парсинг пользователей по чатам/каналам телеграм, работает на aiogram + telethon. В январе 2022 года всё работало корректно. Сейчас же при запуске бота, после ввода номера телефона и кода подтверждения выбрасывает со всех устройств, на которых открыт данный аккаунт, через 10-20 секунд завершается и сессия telethon со следующей ошибкой

```
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.SessionRevokedError: The authorization has been invalidated, because of the user terminating all sessions
```

Также прикладываю фрагмент кода

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

bot = Bot(token=bot_settings.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage() 
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

client = TelegramClient(bot_settings.SESSION_NAME, bot_settings.API_ID, bot_settings.API_HASH)
client.start()

@dp.message_handler(state=ChatOpenLink.waiting_link)
async def get_open_report(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(waiting_link=message.text)
    state_data = await state.get_data()
    link = state_data.get('waiting_link')
    channel = await client.get_entity(link)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Начинаю парсинг, это может занять от 10 до 15 минут⏱')
    upload_message = await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Идёт парсинг: 0%')
    ALL_PARTICIPANTS = []
    for key in bot_settings.QUERY:
        progress = (bot_settings.QUERY.index(key)+1)*100/len(bot_settings.QUERY)
        progress = float('{:.2f}'.format(progress))
        await upload_message.edit_text(text=f'Идёт парсинг: {progress}%')
        OFFSET_USER = 0
        while True:
            participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(channel,ChannelParticipantsSearch(key), OFFSET_USER, bot_settings.LIMIT_USER, hash=0))
            if not participants.users:
                break
            ALL_PARTICIPANTS.extend(participants.users)
            OFFSET_USER += len(participants.users)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
    with client:
        client.loop.run_until_complete()
```

Пробовал менять импорт на

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
```

прописывать

```
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Также оставлял только данные строки

```
client = TelegramClient(bot_settings.SESSION_NAME, bot_settings.API_ID, bot_settings.API_HASH)
client.start()
```

результат всегда один - ошибка либо на этапе получения entity чата, либо парсинг начинается и через 10 секунд выбрасывает из всех сессий.

Не работает ни с номера телефона по которому всё работало в январе, ни с нового аккаунта и нового приложения.

Comment: Там были изменения в апи, в связи с волной фишинга. Говорят, на `pyrogram` работает

Comment: Большое спасибо за информацию

Answer (score 1):

Допишите в TelegramClient *device_model* и *system_version*

как тут для примера:

```
client = TelegramClient(StringSession(SESSION_STRING), api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH, device_model="Linux 5.15.0", system_version="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS")
client.session.save()
```

Раньше этого не требовалось, да и сейчас у многих тоже все работает. Но у некоторых возникает этот глюк с выходом из всех сессий - очень странная ошибка.